# chrome canary buil crashes when webrtc function is called

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

As  i know that Webrtc has been implemented in chrome dev channel . the function  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia('audio', gotStream, gotStreamFailed); is calling when window is loading . I have also enabled chrome://flags " Enable MediaStream " . "gotStream" and "gotStreamFailed" function are not doing nothing in my code . but after some moment of page load  canary build going to crashe.Can anybody help me how to solve this problem . I have gone demo given in link "http://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/running-the-demos" but same problem occur ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the latest version of chromium from the nightly build list:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html

And ensure the version you downloaded is later than 19.0.1061.1.